# jQuery Accordions Using Dynamic Post ID Classes

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, dynamic, accordion

I have jQuery drop down accordions on each post in my loop, and I want to trigger them individually on click. They work by checking div classes, so I've made sure that each class is dynamically named based on the post-ID. I've also created a variable to generate the name of class used in the script...

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
   var post_ID = ".show-dts.<?php the_ID();?>";

   $(post_ID).click(function() {
       if($('.show-more-dts').css('height') != '1px'){
           $('.show-more-dts').stop().animate({height: '1px'}, 200);
           $(this).text('Show details');
       }else{
           $('.show-more-dts').css({height:'100%'});
           var xx = $('.show-more-dts').height();
           $('.show-more-dts').css({height:'1px'});
           $('.show-more-dts').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
           // ^^ The above is beacuse you can't animate css to 100% (or any percentage).  So I change it to 100%, get the value, change it back, then animate it to the value. If you don't want animation, you can ditch all of it and just leave: $('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});^^ //
           $(this).text('Hide Details');
       }return false;
   }); </script>
```

Checking the page source, I can see that the jQuery code is creating the correct class names using  the variable, but I'm not quite there, because when any of the accordions are clicked, all them are triggered together still.

Comment: Please provide a working example so we can test and reproduce the problem

Comment: I can't duplicate it in a snippet, because it uses dynamic classes based on my wordpress post IDs.

Comment: You can post generated content